# Split time series to find annual maximum from a data frame in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a time series dataset as follows where first column is year, second month, third date, and subsequent columns are time series data sets:

```
1995   1    1     0.0   1.929  23.015   1.429   0.806   0.177   0.027
1995   1    2   0.000   1.097  12.954   0.000   0.196   0.361   0.233
1995   1    3   0.000  11.391   0.228   0.004   2.134  11.190   0.028
1995   1    4   0.504   0.373   0.197   0.333   5.894   0.003   0.098
1995   1    5   0.027  20.957   0.115   0.208   0.000   0.000   0.104
1995   1    6   0.043   9.952   0.042   2.499   1.406   0.000   0.748
....   .    .   .....   .....   .....   .....   .....   .....   .....
2000   12   31  50.98   23.23   98.78   34.23   34.54   45.54   34.21
```

I have read it using:

```
pd.read_csv('D:/test.csv')
```

I want to read data columns and find annual maximum value from them. Any suggestion on how to group or split data to find annual maximum values for each variable would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, given your sample dataframe `df`, you can read it with:

```
df = pd.read_csv('D:/test.csv', header=None)
```

and then groupby by column 0 (year) and get the maximum for each value:

```
g = df.groupby(0).max()
```

This returns:

```
      1  2      3       4       5      6      7      8      9
0                                                            
1995  1  6  0.504  20.957  23.015  2.499  5.894  11.19  0.748
```

Comment: I have updated OP and with above expression it returned error:
`File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 696, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12310)`
  `File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 704, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12261)`

Comment: It may depend on the format of the original .csv file. Did you try with the extract sample you posted?

Comment: If you have a complete csv with column headers you don't need the `header=None` while reading.

Comment: Since there are no headers so used `header=None` and there will be 5 maximum annual values for each column. That could be the reason of error?

Comment: If there are multiple equal values the `.max()` should return one of them, so I think that is not the problem. Try copy and paste a larger sample of the full dataframe without reading it from .csv and see what's going on...

Comment: @Fabio: I wasn't even able to get maximum value using sample data frame I provided above. Now I suspect version of either python or pandas causing the error

Comment: @Ibe for me it works with pandas 0.17 and python 2.7.10